# Add a new layer to a tensorflow.python.keras.models.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.3.0.

I want to extract the encoder from a U-Net network and add it `GlobalAveragePooling2D`.

I have used the functional API to define U-Net:

```
inputs = Input(shape=img_shape)

conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv1_1')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv1_2')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool1')(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv2_1')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv2_2')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool2')(conv2)

conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv3_1')(pool2)
conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv3_2')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool3')(conv3)

conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv4_1')(pool3)
conv4 = Conv2D(256, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv4_2')(conv4)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool4')(conv4)

conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv5_1')(pool4)
conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv5_2')(conv5)

up_conv5 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv5')(conv5)
ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv4, up_conv5)
crop_conv4 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv4')(conv4)
up6 = concatenate([up_conv5, crop_conv4])
conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv6_1')(up6)
conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv6_2')(conv6)

up_conv6 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv6')(conv6)
ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv3, up_conv6)
crop_conv3 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv3')(conv3)
up7 = concatenate([up_conv6, crop_conv3])
conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv7_1')(up7)
conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv7_2')(conv7)

up_conv7 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv7')(conv7)
ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv2, up_conv7)
crop_conv2 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv2')(conv2)
up8 = concatenate([up_conv7, crop_conv2])
conv8 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv8_1')(up8)
conv8 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv8_2')(conv8)

up_conv8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv8')(conv8)
ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv1, up_conv8)
crop_conv1 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv1')(conv1)
up9 = concatenate([up_conv8, crop_conv1])
conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_1')(up9)
conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_2')(conv9)

ch, cw = get_crop_shape(inputs, conv9)
conv9 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_3')(conv9)
conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', data_format="channels_last", name='conv10_1')(conv9)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

return model
```

To get the model and add it the `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer I do this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D

encoder_input = Model(inputs=old_model.layers[0].input, outputs=old_model.layers[14].output)

encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input)

encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoder_output, name='encoder')
```

The above code is a modified version of the example from the [Tensorflow's Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional/#use_the_same_graph_of_layers_to_define_multiple_models) web.

I'm doing this way because the U-Net is already pre-trained, so I need to get the encoder from the pre-trained model.

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

At line:

```
encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input)
```

I have also tried, without success:

```
encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input.get_layer('conv5_2'))
```

And:

```
encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input.layers[-1].output)
```

---

How can I add the `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer to the `old_model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do it. I get the idea from this [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3465).

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D

encoder_input = Model(inputs=old_model.layers[0].input, outputs=old_model.layers[14].output)

encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input.layers[-1].output)

encoder = Model(encoder_input.input, encoder_output, name='encoder')
```

The `summary` for the new model (`encoder`) is:

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      1664      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      83040     
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 50, 50, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       1048832   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 512)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384,832
Trainable params: 5,384,832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I hope that the following output shape is correct:

```
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 512)               0         
=================================================================
```

But in [Transfer learning & fine-tuning](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/) there is a similar output shape.